# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' /functions.php on line 1

Tags: wordpress, parsing, syntax-error

This is my functions.php file in my Wordpress theme installation.
http://pastebin.com/rfaxbyUp

Can someone help me figure out why I am getting that error?
Thanks!

Comment: In the pastebin, its all on a single line, starting with a comment that comments out most of it. Is that how it's in your functions.php ( no line endings ) ? If so, add line breaks...

Answer (score 0):

You have no line breaks in your code, which makes incredibly difficult for anybody to help you.

But in the code you gave us, you have `<?php}` two times.  This isn't correct.  It should be `<?php }` with a space between the `php` and the brace.